# SQL find duplicates appointments in a week?

Tags: sql, vba, pivot-table

We are trying to smooth out fluctuations in the usage of our treatment centre.

At the moment we have heavy usage on some days of the week (TUES / THURS) , and not on the others (MON, WED, FRI)

Now often a patient must attend to be reviewed before having their treatment on days with "efficient" doctors who see a lot of patients. The doctors are part-time so cant switch days easily.

However on occasions they attend on the "traditional" (for them) appointment day of week but do not need a review, so it could be possible to move them to another day (forward or back one day).

However this only works if they have (1) appointment in that week (some treatments are multiple days in one week).

So:

1st. Find all patients attending for treatment (LOCATION="CHEMO") in a certain week on each day (M/T/W/T/F) who *do not have* an appointment for review (LOCATION="CLINIC")

2nd. List only patients who *do not have* other treatments in that week.

At the moment I am doing that programmatically in a While look in VBA code.. but I was wondering if their was a better way in SQL to list all the appointments on each day of the week with there ApptComment to see if they are possible moveable.

Table for Appointments:

```
ApptID - autoicrement
ApptDate
ApptTime
PatientID - unique to patient
LocationID - ("CHEMO","REVIEW")
ApptCancelledYN - Boolean
ApptComment - containts the treatment details
```

Answer (score 0):

2)List only patients who do not have other treatments in that week

Let's say user input is some DATE(26th DEC 2014 ->4th week)

```
declare @given_week int  
declare @given_month int  
declare @given_year int  
set @given_week  =(select DATEPART(ww,@GIVEN_DATE)  
set @given_month  =(select DATEPART(mm,@GIVEN_DATE)  
set @given_year  =(select DATEPART(yy,@GIVEN_DATE)
```

--The below query will give you the List of Patients who do not have other treatments in that given week

```
select PatientID, count(PatientID) from 
AppointmentsTable
where DATEPART(ww,ApptDate) = @given_week  
and  DATEPART(mm,ApptDate) = @given_month  
and  DATEPART(yy,ApptDate) = @given_year  
group by PatientID
having count(PatientID) =1

or 

select PatientID,ApptComment, count(PatientID) from 
AppointmentsTable
where DATEPART(ww,ApptDate) = @given_week  
and  DATEPART(mm,ApptDate) = @given_month  
and  DATEPART(yy,ApptDate) = @given_year  
group by PatientID,ApptComment
having count(PatientID) =1
```

-- Include LocationID in where clause if necessary

1)Find all patients attending for treatment (LOCATION="CHEMO") in a certain week on each day (M/T/W/T/F) who do not have an appointment for review (LOCATION="CLINIC")

```
declare @given_week int
declare @given_month int
declare @given_year int
set @given_week  =(select DATEPART(ww,@GIVEN_DATE)
set @given_month  =(select DATEPART(mm,@GIVEN_DATE)
set @given_year  =(select DATEPART(yy,@GIVEN_DATE)

select PatientID from AppointmentsTable 
where DATEPART(ww,ApptDate) = @given_week  
and  DATEPART(mm,ApptDate) = @given_month  
and  DATEPART(yy,ApptDate) = @given_year  
and LocationID = 'CHEMO' and PatientID NOT IN
(
select DISTINCT PatientID from AppointmentsTable 
where DATEPART(ww,ApptDate) = @given_week  
and  DATEPART(mm,ApptDate) = @given_month  
and  DATEPART(yy,ApptDate) = @given_year  
and LocationID = 'CLINIC'
and ApptComment like '%review%'
)
```

Comment: Thanks. 2) certainly does the trick in the first part, though the second part doesn't i think because the ApptComment can be different on different days so it Groups Pat1 "CHEMO DAY1" and Pat1 "Chemo DAY2" as Count = 1.

Comment: But 1) doesn't work as because (my fault I wasn't clear) that if they do have review appointment on that day they can't be moved, but if they had it on a different day that week that would be okay.